# How to redirect stdin from keyboard in a dart script?

Tags: dart

When testing a Dart pre-commit git hook script I wrote, I'm able to type into stdin as input when using a prompt. But when running it through git when committing, it runs through the input calls without prompting the user for input. Apparently, there's a workaround in certain languages, by Calling `exec < /dev/tty` which assigns standard input to the keyboard, but what about in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read directly from /dev/tty as a File instead of redirecting the stdin:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  print('What is your name: ');

  final name = await getUserInput();

  print('Hello! Your name is $name');
}

Future<String> getUserInput() async =>
    File(Platform.isWindows ? r'conIN$' : '/dev/tty')
        .openRead()
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(const LineSplitter())
        .first;
```

I found the following documentation for conIN$ which indicates that this always points to the console input on Windows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles

Comment: Ok, thank you. What about windows? And is there a way to prevent it from exiting after one line? It validates input, so the user would have to get it right on the first try for that to work.

Comment: Well, my comment about the program exiting was more a hint about the /dev/tty file is automatically closed after receiving one line from the user and therefore my example would close because my program don't use the input for anything. I have updated the example to make it easier to understand this aspect.

Comment: About Windows i don't know since I made my example based on you own suggested solution (exec < /dev/tty). I therefore don't know if Windows has something similar.

Comment: Added a working example for Windows. Please try it out and see if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: Just tested it out on Mac and it works PERFECTLY! Thank you SO much!